# android - java - WeakReferences with an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, garbage-collection, weak-references

I know that with a `WeakReference`, if I make a `WeakReference` to something that unless there's a direct reference to it that it will be Garbage Collected with the next GC cycle. My question becomes, what if I make an `ArrayList` of `WeakReference`s?

For example:

```
ArrayList<WeakReference<String>> exArrayList;
exArrayList = new ArrayList<WeakReference<String>>();
exArrayList.add(new WeakReference<String>("Hello"));
```

I can now access the data with `exArrayList.get(0).get()`.

My question becomes: This is `WeakReference` data, will the data located at `exArrayList.get(0)` be GC'd with the next GC cycle? (even IF I don't make another direct reference to it) or will this particular reference stick around until the `arraylist` is emptied? (eg: `exArrayList.clear();`).

If this is a duplicate I haven't found it with my keywords in google.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. `exArrayList.add(new WeakReference<String>("Hello"));` is a bad example because `String` literals are never GC-ed
2. if it were e.g. `exArrayList.add(new WeakReference<Object>(new Object()));` then after a GC the object would be GC-ed, but `exArrayList.get(0)` would still return `WeakReference`, though `exArrayList.get(0).get()` would return `null`

Answer (score 7):

The data at `exArrayList.get(0)` is the `WeakReference`. It is not by itself a weak reference, so it will not be collected...

BUT the object referenced by `exArrayList.get(0)` is weakly referenced, so it **might** be GCed at any time (of course, that requires that there are no *strong* references to that object).

So

`data.get(0)` won't become `null`, but `data.get(0).get()` might become.

In other words, the list does not references the weak referenced object but the weak reference itself.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad idea as the other posters explained above (reference objects not freed). Use a WeakHashMap with the objects as keys and some dummy values ("" or Boolean.TRUE or similar).

Comment: I see a lesser concern in "reference objects not freed" than the tremendous overhead of a HashMap where you don't really need it.

Comment: I do sometimes use List<WeakReference<A>> for lack of a LinkedWeakHashMap. Just make sure to clean the list sometimes.

Comment: HashMap doesn't have that much overhead. The point here is that its overhead is a fixed factor, whereas the List approach can grow indefinitely, even if no objects are actually in it anymore.